# Using PyLatex to create importable Tex files

Tags: import, pylatex

Using PyLaTex, I currently I have to use an editor to strip off the "/usepackage{'foo'}" statements from PyLaTex generated external tex files so that my main.py file can open, read and append each external tex file. The resulting main.tex file builds correctly but I don't want to have to manually edit the external tex files each time. Any ideas?

Comment: We can't be sure without an MWE, but it sound like declaring `\renewcommand*\usepackage[2][]{}` for the time of the inclusion should work.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this problem:

You can generate tex files not only from pylatex.Document, but also from pylatex.Section objects (Section,Subsection,..):

```
 def generate_tex(self, your_title, path, file_name):
    section = Section(your_title)

    # add some stuff to your section

    file_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
    section.generate_tex(filepath=file_path)
```

This generates a tex file without package declarations.

"file_name.tex":

```
\subsection{your_title}%
%your added stuff
```